# How to set a default user in xcode7 with the help of objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

I'm trying to build and login and logout application, but not able to login please help me to set default user id and password through which i would be able go to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code it will help you :

```
    -(void)login
    {


        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/pm/api/login"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];

      [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


        [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=admin&password=123456&api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6"];

           NSData *postData = [mapData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if(error == nil)
            {

                NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                if(error!=nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self checkUserSuccessfulLogin:json];
                });
            }
            else{

                NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);

            }


        }];


        [postDataTask resume];

    }
    - (void)checkUserSuccessfulLogin:(id)json
    {
      //  NSError *error;
       NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;


        if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login"])
        {
            if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"login"] boolValue])
            {

                if(checkBoxSelected == YES)
                {
                    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    NSString* textField1Text = usernameField.text;
                    [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

                    NSString *textField2Text = passwordField.text;
                    [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
                    [defaults synchronize];
                }
                NSString *strID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField1Text"];
                NSString *strPWD = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField2Text"];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];
              NSString *strUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
                [self saveLoginFileToDocDir:dictionary];


                ItemManagement *i = [[ItemManagement alloc]init];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Unsuccessful, Try again.");
                UIAlertView *alertLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Wrong Username Or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertLogin show];
            }
        }
    }




    - (void)saveLoginFileToDocDir:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
    {
        NSArray *pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

        BOOL flag = [dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:true];

        if (flag)
        {
            NSLog(@"Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Not Saved");
        }

    }

    - (NSDictionary *)getLoginFileFromDocDir
    {
        NSArray*pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,  YES);
        NSString*pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

        return dict;
    }


-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected;
    [checkbox setSelected:checkBoxSelected];


}
```

Comment: Brother I'm glad your replied to my query but in this code you are connecting to the service right i wanna create a local database too.. can you help me that ?? @Aayushkatiyar

Comment: Is it possible to use sql lite ? @aayush katiyar

Comment: yes it is possible to create sql database using code but it is bitter tough, so now the developers use core data it is feasable, if you want to learn about core data then go to this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: Thankyou So much @Aayushkatiyar 
can i just login with a default user and password without connecting it to server

Comment: yes we can do it and the code above which i have posted it is login without the server, only i am passing the api and their parameters and api key if parametr matches then it will go to itemmanagemnt page

Comment: Hey @AayushKatiyar 
if(checkBoxSelected == YES) is giving an issue suggest me a alternative for a checkbox

Comment: See the code above and the error i'm getting is {Use of undeclared identifier 'CheckBoxSelected'} .. I'm Actually new to Xcode so not able to figure out. @AbhinandanPratap

Comment: may be it is a function which @aayush forgot to mention in answer

Comment: Now it's showing 

{linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)}

@AayushKatiyar

Comment: now its showing 
{linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)}
@AbhinandanPratap

Comment: I'm guessing it was because you have duplicate symbols. It is probably something defined in a header file that should be in a source file.

Comment: I'm Blank i don't know what is going on @AayushKatiyar

Comment: see may be you have used same name two times or more in your file check it that no object or any thing having same name more than once

Answer (score 0):

to set a default user in app you may use the code below

In your `AppDelegate.m`

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"IsFirstTime"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            ViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
        }
        else
        {

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"IsFirstTime"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
```

then `#import` your `AppDelegate.m` class to the class where you put code for login

```
AppDelegate *delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    delegate  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://43.252.88.251/jsonandroid/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=admin&password=123456&api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6"];

    NSData *postData = [mapData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(error == nil)
        {

            NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if(error!=nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self checkUserSuccessfulLogin:json];
            });
        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);

        }


    }];


    [postDataTask resume];

}
- (void)checkUserSuccessfulLogin:(id)json
{
    //  NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;


    if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login"])
    {
        if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"login"] boolValue])



            {
                NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                NSString* textField1Text = usernamefield.text;
                [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

                NSString *textField2Text = passwordfield.text;
                [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
                [defaults synchronize];
            }
            NSString *strID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField1Text"];
            NSString *strPWD = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField2Text"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];
            NSString *strUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            [self saveLoginFileToDocDir:dictionary];


            /* ItemManagement *ItemManagement = [[ItemManagement alloc]init];
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:ItemManagement animated:YES];
             */

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Unsuccessful, Try again.");
            /* UIAlertView *alertLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Wrong Username Or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertLogin show];*/

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Hello" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


            UIAlertAction *cancelbutton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
            //UIAlertAction *oktext= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:oktext style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

            [alert addAction:cancelbutton];
            //[alert addAction:oktext];
        }

    }







- (void)saveLoginFileToDocDir:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

    BOOL flag = [dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:true];

    if (flag)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Saved");
    }

}

- (NSDictionary *)getLoginFileFromDocDir
{
    NSArray*pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,  YES);
    NSString*pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: This is the code im not able to login nor able to find the pop up of alert @Aayush